# How to change the melt.data.frame function in reshape2 package returned "variable" column to "character" class?

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, melt

The default behavior of melt.data.frame is to return the "variable" column in "factor" class. Here is an example:

```
> head(airquality)

  ozone solar.r wind temp month day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6

> x = melt(head(airquality))
Using  as id variables

> head(x)
  variable value
1    ozone    41
2    ozone    36
3    ozone    12
4    ozone    18
5    ozone    NA
6    ozone    28

> class(x$variable)
[1] "factor"
```

The question is that is there any parameter to change the class from factor to character? I tried `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` but it is not working.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is such an option built into `melt.data.frame`. However, if you inspect the code, it's not hard to change. We can define a new function `melt.df` that replaces the relevant line with a quick check to see if the user has set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`:

```
if (getOption("stringsAsFactors")){
    df[[variable_name]] <- factor(df[[variable_name]], 
                                   unique(df[[variable_name]]))
}
else{
   df[[variable_name]] <- as.character(factor(df[[variable_name]],         
                                   unique(df[[variable_name]])))
}
```

I checked this on your simple example and it worked as expected, but I haven't checked it more generally, so beware. I'm not convinced this modification won't produce surprising behavior in other circumstances.

Comment: I think you'd be better off wrapping melt in another function that does `df$variable <- as.character(df$variable)`

Comment: @hadley, this is an inconvenience when working with dates. Works, though.

Comment: @dmvianna please file an issue with small example at https://github.com/hadley/reshape/issues

Comment: @hadley It’s not straightforward to have a generic wrapper: `melt.data.frame` has a different argument name for the variables column than `melt.matrix` (`variable.name` vs `varnames`). It would be better if the actual `melt` could be made to use characters instead of a factor.

Answer (score 5):

With most users heading over to either the "tidyverse" or "data.table" for reshaping data these days, your options have improved.

In the "tidyverse", the default behavior is to keep the molten variable as `character`s:

```
library(tidyverse)
airquality %>% gather(var, val, everything()) %>% str()
# 'data.frame': 918 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ var: chr  "Ozone" "Ozone" "Ozone" "Ozone" ...
#  $ val: num  41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
```

In the "data.table" implementation of `melt`, a few new arguments have been added, one of which is `variable.factor` which can be set to `FALSE`. It's set to `TRUE` by default for, I believe, consistency with the "reshape2" implementation of `melt`.

```
library(data.table)
str(melt(as.data.table(airquality), variable.factor = FALSE))
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    36 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ variable: chr  "Ozone" "Ozone" "Ozone" "Ozone" ...
#  $ value   : num  41 36 12 18 NA 28 190 118 149 313 ...
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```